# XSLT - how to specify ordered or dependent actions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a single xslt template that simplifies source code as follows:
1) Remove element *p* if empty
2) "Unwrap" contents of element *p* if it is the only instance of element *p* at the current level.

The challenge I have is that the condition for action #2 is not apparent until action #1 is complete. My question is, is there a way to specify "do action #2 after action #1 is complete"?

To give specifics, my template would detect the following

```
<li><p>Some words</p></li>
```

and simplify it as:

```
<li>Some words</li>
```

But if I run into this:

```
<li><p>Some words</p><p/></li>
```

action #1 will be applied, but action #2 will not, resulting in:

```
<li><p>Some words</p></li>
```

rather than the intended:

```
<li>Some words</li>
```

My template is as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(.) = '' and not(@conref) and .[not(*)]">
            <xsl:message>Delete empty p.</xsl:message>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="parent::li[count(p)=1 and not(./p[@id]) and not(./p[@conref])]">
            <xsl:message>Unwrap superfluous p.</xsl:message>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:message>Print p as is.</xsl:message>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Remove element p if empty
>   2) "Unwrap" contents of element p if it is the only instance of element p at the current level.
>   ...
>   My question is, is there a way to specify "do action #2 after action
>    #1 is complete"?

I believe these rules could be consolidated into one:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[not(@* or node()) or not((preceding-sibling::p|following-sibling::p)[@* or node()])]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test input:**

```
<root>
    <li>
        <p></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>a</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>b</p>
        <p>c</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>d</p>
        <p></p>
    </li>
</root>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <li/>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>
      <p>b</p>
      <p>c</p>
   </li>
   <li>d</li>
</root>
```

Note that applying templates from the context of an empty element is benign.

Comment: Thanks, the combined rule is certainly cleaner, but it doesn't address the primary issue, wherein the rectification of condition one (removal of empty p) *results in* condition two (single instance of populated p), thus necessitating a second pass with the current template.  Using your example, I'm looking to resolve <li><p>b</p></p></li> (node with one populated p child and any number of unpopulated p children, in any order) to <li>b</li>. Maybe I need a loop of some sort?  I suspect that would be inelegant though.

Comment: @wolfmason I was just now editing my answer in response to your editing the question - see if this provides an answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't duplicate your results, even after replacing my source and xsl doc completely with the above examples.

Comment: @wolfmason You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQf2 Which processor are you using?

Comment: Saxon 9x he.  Your template works fine in place of mine on xsltransform  in the context of my full transform, and with my full content.  Not sure why I can't get the same results out of the local parser.  Seems like it doesn't respond to p[not(@* or node()).  Fun...

Comment: (and now I'm seeing that my original template works on xsltransform.net as well, so I'm clearly dealing with some local weirdness that I can't explain.  Marking correct for your valiant effort.)